# Differentiating Plasma Wave Modes Using Phase Difference

Tags: waves, maxwell-equations, plasma-physics, dispersion

[image]Graphically, the four plasma wave modes for 'cold' plasma overlap for various frequencies. According to *Fundamentals of Plasma Physics* by Bittencourt, the dispersion relations characterize an $\omega$-k relationship. The RCP (right circularly polarized) wave mode has a lower and an upper band. The lower band is defined by $\omega_c$ > $\omega$, while the upper band is $\omega_2$ < $\omega$. The other bands for LCP (left circularly polarized), O (ordinary), and X (extraordinary) are for $\omega_1$ < $\omega$. My question is in page 436 of Bittencourt; how can I differentiate between the various plasma wave modes in the upper bands.

Would I need to measure an electric field and choose an arbitrary k vector? Thereby, allowing me to solve for B in the Maxwell-Faraday equation? Using the dispersion relations found in Bittencourt, it is possible to solve for k by choosing a range of $\omega$. What procedure would be recommended for this undertaking? Is finding the phase difference the only method available to differentiate between plasma wave modes at the same frequency?

Comment: Is there any chance you can attach an image of the figure to which you are referring or provide more context?  For instance, I could make assumptions about what is meant by things like $\omega_{1}$ but the answer actually depends upon the correct definition, not my assumptions.  Also, when you ask about phase differencing, are you asking about applying this to data or just doing the paper-and-pencil theory?  That is, what are the conditions for finding the solutions?

Comment: I am looking for a way to find a general solution that I can apply for a range of $\omega$ in a MATLAB script. I have attempted to solve for the phase difference for waves E_rcp and B_rcp, but I am unsure how to differentiate between all the waves.